# Where is the "Register Now" button on the Facebook Developers homepage? It isn't appearing for me

Tags: facebook, omniauth, registration, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to set up a Facebook Developer account. According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/create-developer-account), I need to visit the [Facebook Developers homepage](https://developers.facebook.com/) and then click the "Register Now" button at the top. However, that button doesn't seem to show up. I have tried going to that page while logged in and while not logged in. Did they move it? Or is there something else going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sign into your account and navigate to https://developers.facebook.com, click on the 'apps' dropdown menu at the top of the page, then 'Register as a Developer'. From there you go through the process of registering and complete it, thereby receiving developer privileges.

I believe that doc you linked is old and outdated and should be updated.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have looked around harder!